# How to use \unimathsetup with fontsetup?

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math, fontsetup

I desire to have an upright partial. I wrote the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontsetup}
\unimathsetup{partial=upright}
\usepackage{fontsetup}

\begin{document}
    \[\partial\]
\end{document}
```

The `unicode-math` documentation says that some package options affect how maths is initialised and changing an option such as math-style will not take effect until a new maths font is set up. So I have loaded the fontsetup package once again after the `\unimath` command to so that the maths fonts are loaded. But this doesn't work and I get an italic partial. Why is this happening and how do I rectify it? I would prefer not to manually load the `unicode-math` and all the fonts separately.

Comment: Loading a package twice will do nothing.

Comment: `\PassOptionsToPackage{partial=upright}{unicode-math}\usepackage{fontsetup}` (just once) should suffice.

Comment: @frabjous Ah, that works! Can you please add that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Elaborating slightly on my comment to make it an "answer"…)

As @egreg pointed out in the comments, when packages are loaded more than once, they are not processed again.

In this particular use case, the `\PassOptionsToPackage` command comes in handy: you can use it so that when fontsetup loads unicode-math, it'll do so with the option(s) you pre-select.

So you can just use:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{partial=upright}{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontsetup}
```